# NSFetchRequest predicate with BOOL check is SLOW

Tags: iphone, core-data

Consider the following 2 predicates filtering through a 5k+ entries store:

```
predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == NO AND name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchString];
predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchString];
```

I turned on `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` to see the fetch request times:

predicate1: 0.4728s
predicate2: **0.0867s**

Am I missing something? Both columns are indexed. How come adding a simple boolean check slows down the fetch request that much?

**EDIT**: as requested, the output:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZHIDDEN, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZRANK FROM ZARTISTINDEX t0 WHERE ( t0.ZHIDDEN = ? AND ( NSCoreDataStringSearch( t0.ZNAME, ?, 393, 0) OR  NSCoreDataStringSearch( t0.ZNAME, ?, 393, 0))) ORDER BY t0.ZRANK DESC LIMIT 14
```

That `rank` column is also indexed. The reason I need this request to be faster than 0.5s is that it's used for an autocomplete feature. That request is made every time the value of some text field gets changed by the user.

**EDIT 2**: adding more contextual info:

```
- (NSArray*)autocompleteSuggestions:(NSString*)searchString {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArtistIndex" inManagedObjectContext:self.indexObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setFetchLimit:10];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hidden == NO AND (name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ OR name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)", searchString, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the %@", searchString]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"rank" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSArray *resultsArray = [self.indexObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    [request release];

    return resultsArray;
}
```

The `ArtistIndex` entity has the following attributes:

- id (int32)
- name (string, indexed)
- rank (int32, indexed)
- hidden (BOOL, indexed)

**Edit 3**: here are the full SQL outputs for the [slow query (predicate1)](http://samv.me/8U25) and the [fast query (predicate2)](http://samv.me/8T8J) with `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` set to 3. More rigorous testing brought me the following test times, which are better, but still have a +2x difference and really make a difference in an autocomplete suggestions context. Or is this a reasonable fetch time difference now?

predicate1: 0.3772s
predicate2: **0.1633s**

Comment: of course it will take time. what u want?

Comment: Of course it will, but @RakeshBhatt, that amount of time is just plain ridiculous.

Comment: That's a bit odd - (have you tried with hidden=NO first? Yea, shouldn't make a difference I know but might help?). Can you post the output of your SQL statements so we can see more whats going on?

Comment: Added the SQL output. Putting hidden == NO first doesn't seem to help much. To put you guys in context, this is for an autocomplete suggestions feature, so it has got to be as fast as possible.

Comment: How many records are you searching - this extra bit of predicate might push up the memory usage and start paging; this could cause the massive jump in the query time?

Comment: @deanWombourne a little more than 5,000

Comment: Well, that's just odd - you're right, it shouldn't take that long at all! What happens if you limit the number of results (say to 50)?

Comment: I already set fetchLimit to 10 (for some reason it doesn't always translate to LIMIT 10 in the SQL output)

Comment: I think the most helpful information would be to post the results of running with SQL Debugging set to level 3 for both queries. You can do this by passing this argument to your app and launching it from Xcode: -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits added that to the question. Let me know if it's any help. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Did you try to remove the index on the hidden field and see the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up taking advice on [@pothibo](http://twitter.com/pothibo) and Ivo Jansch's answer 2nd approach and do the following:

1. When the user types in the first letter in the field, I fetch all the entries that
   start with that letter (so basically calling that `autocompleteSuggestions:` method but without setting the fetch request's
   `fetchLimit` property)
2. Every time the user adds or remove a letter, apply an appropriate
   `NSPredicate` to that initially fetched array using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

This results in a slighly slower initial request (although still < 1s) but lightning-fast subsequent fetches.

This is a really clever way to do autocomplete suggestions, since the new set of autocomplete suggestions is *always* going to be a subset of the previous one. Thanks @pothibo!

Answer (score 2):

With a where clause on 2 columns and indexes on only 1, sqlite is probably deciding to use the index on the boolean field. That leads to a fast select, but it will result internally in having half your data set loaded; then it starts to do the other clause, but it needs to do that by looking at every record. That's why the boolean search is causing the slowdown.

I think there are 3 approaches you should try.

1. Queries on 2 columns will perform poor unless there is one index on both columns. I don't believe Core Data lets you index multiple columns in a single index yet, but the underlying SQLite database does. So just to see if this is what's causing the issue, try to manually create an index on your sqlite database on both columns. It is important that your boolean value is the second column in the index, as it's not distinctive enough (it only has 2 values so the data set it needs to filter is half your database; this makes indexing slightly less efficient).
2. Add a utility column that contains a concatenation of the name and hidden fields and have that indexed and search on that. This might be less effective though since you're matching substrings.
3. If the amount of records with hidden=YES is small, just leave it out of the predicate and filter them afterwards.

Comment: Not sure I follow on approach #1. Both columns are marked as "indexed" in the Core Data scheme editor. Unless the scheme editor allows it but isn't in sync with what Core Data supports? Approaches 2 and 3 are great ideas. Will give both a spin and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: If you mark both as 'indexed', it creates 2 indexes, each on a single column. What you need is 1 index on 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData isn't' really doing a whole lot here between those two queries. There are two possible causes for this slowdown, both can be diagnosed by setting -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3 on your application launch arguments in Xcode.

1. Your slow query is hitting two indexes and for some reason this is slow in SQLite
2. Your slow query's SQL is not generated correctly

Solutions:

1. Update to iOS 5 Beta 3 and use multi-column indexing in your data model to index your hidden and name attributes
2. bugreport.apple.com with your application's data store and SQL debug log for both queries.

Comment: Added the full SQL output to the original question. I still need my app to be 4.0 compatible. I'm assuming that multi-column indexing feature would only work for iOS 5 users?

Comment: Yep, multi-column indexes are iOS 5 only. The output looks "correct" for what I would expect, and the difference in fetch times does appear to be due to hitting both indexes.